# CRM Online : An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am new to MS Dynamics CRM. I am updating huge amount of data using Microsoft C# CRM SDK. I am using batch update by processing batch of 1000 records(Using ExecuteMultipleRequest). Code works just fine and is able to update records too. But recently I had to update a large bunch of data > 6,00,000 records. After around 150 batches (1,50,000) successful updates, code suddenly starts throwing below exception:

> An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.System.ServiceModel.FaultException: At least one security token in the message could not be validated.

Please note that this behavior is consistent. When I again execute the program it would update normally but after 150-160 batches, it will again start throwing same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think there's usually an inner exception to go along with that Exception type. That might give you a little more information

Answer (score 0):

Plese check that your security token is not expiring. I.E. if your code looks like

```
using(var organizationService = new OrganizationServiceProxy(...)) {
  // long running batches
  foreach(var batch in batches) {
    // import batch using organizationService 
  }
}
```

Change your code to

```
foreach(var batch in batches) {
  using(var organizationService = new OrganizationServiceProxy(...)) {
    // import batch using organizationService 
  }
}
```